# Power charger Asus laptop

Tags: laptop, power, charger

My model number X550L is not mentioned in a list of compatable modal numbers. Some look close to me i.e. few letters different X550CA X550CC X550VB and the one shown is 19v 3.42A witch would match the one that came with the laptop I don't know if its a stranded fit or witch model number I should select if any?
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Asus-19V-3-42A-ADP-65JH-BB-04G2660031U0-Compatible-Laptop-AC-Adapter-Charger-/131523345809?var=&hash=item1e9f66fd91:m:mZQCclaU7v1vdIMF2VgBrhA

The charger that came with the laptop and Is now having issues is 19v 3.42A I can see much useful other than that as it all seems to be in Chinese witch I cant read.
Thank you ST34M. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Power-supply-Adapter-Asus-X550C-X550E-X550LN-X550LD-X550L-laptop-charger-Cable-/281547118792?hash=item418d8418c8:g:ozMAAOSwcwhVO0Vl

This one will work fine for your laptop X550L.